# Update intent extras value when activity in background

Tags: android

my app is in background. When I get notification I use pending intent to open my activity. The problem is that extras are not updated correctly. (seems that they are not passed to activity) When I kill app and open via notification then I get correct extras.

```
val messageIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
messageIntent.setAction("foo");  
messageIntent.putExtra("sth", true);
messageIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
pendingMessageIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this, 0, messageIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
```

How can I update my intent extras in MainActivity even if I open notification from background?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `onNewIntent` to your Activity:

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    this.intent = intent
}
```